# Organize Questions & Answers from database in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, schema

In my database I have questions and answers. Every post has a 'postID' and only answers have a 'responseID', which references the 'postID' of the question.

I can identify which answers go to which question since responseID = postID

I'd like to write some php code that would display the data in the following format:

Question:
- answer
- answer
- answer

Question:
- answer
- answer
- answer

...and so on

Additional Info:
The Questions and Answers are in the same tblQA table. The colums are QAID, PosterID, ResponseID, TimeStamp, Category, Body.

So, every post has a QAID. A question would have a category, and an answer would have a responseID that equaled the questions QAID.

This would grab ALL questions:
    SELECT * FROM tblQA WHERE category IS NOT NULL

This would grab all answers:
    SELECT * FROM tblQA WHERE ResponseID IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tblQA WHERE category IS NOT NULL";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   echo $row[Body];
   $sql1="SELECT * FROM tblQA WHERE ResponseID IS NOT NULL and qaid =  $row[responseid]";
   $result = mysql_query($sql1);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
      echo $row[Body];
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't changed the database because of an application that is hardcoded to use the db as it is right now.

Answer (score 3):

Looping isn't necessary. You can do a SQL query that uses a `JOIN`.

If your tables looks like this:

```
QuestionID       Question
123              "What do you think about..."
124              "Who is your favorite..."

AnswerID         Answer
123              "I think that..."
123              "I tend to think..."
124              "My favorite..."
```

You could craft a `JOIN` query something like

`SELECT * FROM Questions LEFT JOIN Answers ON QuestionID = AnswerID`

This isn't tested, but that's the theory. What that will give you for results is something like

```
QuestionID       Question                        Answer
123              "What do you think about..."    "I think that..."
123              "What do you think about..."    "I tend to think..."
```

There are a number of `JOIN`s you can do depending on your RDBMS. Mostly the flavors have to do with which "side" of the join takes priority when there's a conflict or a `null` value.

Read more about `MySQL` here: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

Comment: Alex, thanks. I'm kinda a rookie at this. Could I please see a small example?

Comment: The questions and answers are in the same table, 'tblQA', so this wouldn't work. SOrry, I should have specified this.

Comment: I would NOT recommend the MySQL docs; they're really hard to comprehend as a beginner. Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you specify your schema a bit more? What columns do you have?